# Versioning, CI, build automation best practices

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, versioning

I am looking for some advice on the best practice for versioning software.

**Background**

Build automation with gradle.

Continuous integration with Jenkins

CVS as SCM

Semantic Versioning

Sonatype Nexus inhouse repo

**Question**

Lets say I make a change to come code. An automated CI job will pull it in and run some tests against it. If these tests should pass, should Jenkins update the version of the code and push it to nexus? Should it be pushed up as a "SNAPSHOT"? Should it be pushed up to nexus at all, or instead just left in the repository until I want to do a release?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

I know you said you are using CVS, but first of all, have you checked the git-flow methodology?
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

I have little experience with CVS, but it can be applied to it, and a good versioning and CI procedure begins with having well defined branches, basically at least one for the latest release, and one for the latest in-development version.

With this you can tell the CI application what it is working with.

---

Didn't have time for a more detailed answer before, so I will extend now, trying to give a general answer.

### Branches

Once you have clearly defined branches you can control your work flow. For example, it is usual having a 'master' and a 'develop' branches, where the master will contain the latest release, and develop will contain the next release.

This means you can always point to the latest release of the code, it is in the master branch, while the next version is in the develop branch. Of course, this can be more detailed, such as tagging the master branch for the various releases, or having an additional branch for each main feature, but it is enough having these two.

Following this, if you need to change something to the code, you edit the develop branch, and make sure it is all correct, then keep making changes until you are happy with the current version, and move this code to the master.

### Tests

Now, how to make sure all is correct and valid? By including tests in your project. There is a lot which can be read about testing, but let's keep it simple. There are two main types of tests:

- White box tests, where you know the insides of the code, and prepare the tests for the specific implementation, making sure it is built as you want
- Black box tests, where you don't know how the code is implemented (or at least, you act as if you didn't), and prepare more generic tests, meant to make sure it works as expected

Now, going to the next step, you won't hear much about these two tests, and instead people will talk about the following ones:

- Unit tests, where you test the smallest piece of code possible
- Integration test, where you connect several pieces of code and test them

"The smallest piece of code possible" has a lot of different meanings, depending on the person and project. But keeping with the simplification, if you can't make a white box test of it, then you are creating an integration test.

Integration tests include things like database access, running servers, and take a long time. At least much longer than unit testing. Also, integration tests due to their complexity may require setting up a specific environment.

This means that while unit tests can be run locally with ease, integration tests may be so slow that people dislike running them, or may just be impossible to run in your machine.

So what do you do? Easy, separate the tests, so unit tests can be run locally after each change, while integration test are run (after unit tests) by the CI server after each commit.

#### Additional tests

Just as a comment, don't stop at this simplified vision of tests. There are several ways of handling tests, and some tests I wouldn't fit into unit or integration tests. For example it is always a good idea validating code style rules, or you can make a test which just deploys the project into a server, to make sure it doesn't break.

### CI

Your CI server should be listening to commits, and if correctly configured it will know when this commit comes from a development version, a release or anything else. Allowing you to customise the process as you wish.

First of all it should run all the tests. No excuses, and don't worry if it takes two hours, it should run all the tests, as this is your shield against future problems.

If there are errors, then the CI server will stop and send a warning. Fix the code and start again. If all tests passed, then congratulations.

Now it is the time to deploy.

Deploying should be taken with care, always. The latest version available in the dependencies repository should, always, be the most current one.

It is nice having a script to deploy the releases into the repository after a commit, but unless you have some short of final validation, a manual human-controlled one at it, you may end releasing a bad version.

Of course, you may ignore this for development versions, as long as they are segregated from the actual releases, but otherwise it is best handling the final deployment by hand.

Well, it may be with a script or whatever you prefer, but it should be you who begins the deployment of releases, not the machine.

#### CI customisation

Having a CI server allows for much more than just testing and building.

Do you like reports? Then generate a test coverage report, a quality metrics one, or whatever you prefer. You are using a external service for this? Then send him the files and let it work.

Your project contains files to generate documentation? Build it and store it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doesnt quite answer my question but provides some nice information about versioning, release, and git. I do, however, prefer the model described  [here](https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/)